# Run RGBDSLAM program computer configuration requirements

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I want to achieve RGBDSLAM procedures, but do not know the requirements of this program on your computer's performance.cpu, Gpu has what requirements?Or what is the minimum configuration?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43491/run-rgbdslam-program-computer-configuration-requirements/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-10-18**:
@yangyangcv  It seems that you have RGBDSLAM running success.I want to know your specific process in accordance with the method on the website, I always can not succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well, the following is my computer's configuration:

CPU: intel i5-2400 @3.1GHz

RAM: 4G

graphics card: ATI Radeon HD 5450

with this configuration, i can get about 10 fps

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1